# Smalltalk: How to make a hyperlink

Tags: hyperlink, smalltalk

In smalltalk, How can I add to string a link

example :

I have a string str = "trial string"

I want to add another string to it but when I click on it I go to some destination

and str will appear like

trial string

Comment: What smalltalk distribution are you using?

Comment: And, where are you showing the string? It's in a Morphic window, or are you making a Seaside website?

Comment: I'M using visual works. 
and the string in a Morphic window.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Seaside you can use the following piece of code when your component will be rendered.

```
renderContentOn: html
  html anchor
    url: 'http://www.seaside.st';
    with: 'Visit the Seaside'.
```

Answer (score 0):

In any programming language, strings are just sequences of characters. Wether or not a hyperlink (in html markup language) is shown as a clickable link, as it is shown in a web browser, depends on how the string is interpreted by the editor/viewer that shows it.

If you want to show hyperlinks in Smalltalk code, I don't know of any Smalltalk IDE that has support for that. But I would not be surprised if there is some project out there that supports doing that.